# Hide master record type

Tags: profile, record-type, contentversion

In Content Version, I have a record type say 'ABC' which is assigned to profile 'XYZ'. But when I log in as the profile XYZ, I'm getting a field called Record Type with the options 'General' and 'ABC'. Can I not make the record type 'ABC' default for that user and remove the record type field?

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can make this RecordType default. Just go to their profile> Go to Object and make the record Type default. Then this option will not come.

[image: Reference]

Comment: Did that but it's still coming. When the record is to be created, the picklist value of the record type will be 'ABC' but the picklist also contains 'General' in it and I'm not able to get rid of that

Comment: Is this a custom page?

Comment: Nope, it's the standard page.

Comment: SO you can remove this field from UI. Also are you talking about detail page. because when we first create a record we get an option to select record type.

Comment: No, I'm talking about only when we create the record. Could you please tell me or send the link of any related docs for the issue?